# Match Enum Values With A Class Fields

Tags: java, oop, java-8, enums, switch-statement

I have an enum and POJO classes in JAVA. In enum class, each enum value matches with variables of POJO classes... And then I want to create a relationship between two classes.

Enum Class:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
   FIELD1,
   FIELD2,
   FIELD3,
   ...
}
```

POJO Class:

```
public class MyPojo
{
   private String field1;
   private String field2_not_ref;
   private String field3;
   ...
}
```

Then, when I try to match these fields of two classes, I've implemented code like:

```
public String matchMethod(MyEnum myenum)
{
  switch(myenum)
  {
   case FIELD1:
      return field1;
   case FIELD2:
      return field2_not_ref;
    ...
  }
}
```

I think that it is not a good/clear solution. Is there any suggestion?

Comment: When do you set the values of fields1,2,3 ?

Comment: @azro, In my main method, ...myMainMethod(MyPojo myPojo, MyEnum myenum) { ... Object matchResult = myPojo.matchMethod(myEnum); ... }

Comment: Do I see it right, that you want the POJO fields to be variable? Or should these fields be immutable? I mean, does the Mapping hat to be applied for chaning values in `MyPojo`?

Comment: @JanHeld, question is so clear. I need to match enum fields with POJO fields. As a result, I will use it like;  `new MyPOJO.getFieldByEnum(myEnum) -> return matched field`; This is not related with immutable/mutable things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To avoid reflection, which might be slow and make things more concise, than with defining method on an enum, you can create an enum with a field that is a function consuming `MyPojo` and returning `String`:

```
public enum MyEnum {
    FIELD1(MyPojo::getField1),
    FIELD2(MyPojo::getField2),
    FIELD3(MyPojo::getField3);

    private final Function<MyPojo, String> getField;

    MyEnum(Function<MyPojo, String> getField) {
        this.getField = getField;
    }
}
```

Then you can call it in the following way:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyPojo myPojo = new MyPojo("f1", "f2", "f3");
    System.out.println(MyEnum.FIELD2.getGetField().apply(myPojo));
}
```

If you don't want to use it as a `Function` variable with `apply` method, you can create a single function on en enum, that does it:

```
public enum MyEnum {
    FIELD1(MyPojo::getField1),
    FIELD2(MyPojo::getField2),
    FIELD3(MyPojo::getField3);

    private final Function<MyPojo, String> getField;

    MyEnum(Function<MyPojo, String> getField) {
        this.getField = getField;
    }

    String getFieldFromMyPojo(MyPojo myPojo) { return getField.apply(myPojo); }
}
```

And invoke it like that:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyPojo myPojo = new MyPojo("f1", "f2", "f3");
    System.out.println(MyEnum.FIELD2.getFieldFromMyPojo(myPojo));
}
```

Getters and setters were omitted for brevity.

Comment: I vote for the second alternative, with the apply internal to the enum.

Comment: Wasn't the OP's whole idea to NOT call MyEnum.FIELD2 or other specific enum type each time? Even the switch presented by @Sha was much more generic than this approach.

Comment: @PiotrNiewinski so you're saying, that the whole switch in the question is a better approach than simply writing `myenum.getFieldFromMyPojo(myPojo)`?

Comment: @Andronicus not at all, I am saying that it may suggest that OP was looking for more generic answer, at least signature of `matchMethod` suggests so

Comment: Hmm. "And then I want to create a relationship between two classes." Made me feel free to design enum to be aware of the entity.

Comment: @Andronicus how to set the class fields based on enum value?

Answer (score 2):

There is one more way:

Define an abstract method in enum and override for every enum field:

```
public enum MyEnum {
    FIELD1 {
        @Override
        public String getFromPojo(MyPojo myPojo) {
            return myPojo.getField1();
        }
    },
    FIELD2 {
        @Override
        public String getFromPojo(MyPojo myPojo) {
            return myPojo.getField2();
        }
    },
    FIELD3 {
        @Override
        public String getFromPojo(MyPojo myPojo) {
            return myPojo.getField3();
        }
    };

    public abstract String getFromPojo(MyPojo myPojo);
}
```

For class `MyPojo` define getters for fields:

Define also method `matchMethod` in a way that it will handle the responsibility to the enum (if you wish, this is not mandatory, since enum can resolve the field by itself).

```
public class MyPojo {

    private String field1;
    private String field2;
    private String field3;

    public MyPojo(String field1, String field2, String field3) {
        this.field1 = field1;
        this.field2 = field2;
        this.field3 = field3;
    }

    public String getField1() {
        return field1;
    }

    public String getField2() {
        return field2;
    }

    public String getField3() {
        return field3;
    }

    public String matchMethod(MyEnum myEnum) {
        return myEnum.getFromPojo(this);
    }
}
```

Now in "main" method you can use the following approach:

```
 MyPojo p1 = new MyPojo("p1", "p2", "p3");
 MyPojo p2 = new MyPojo("k1", "k2", "k3");

 System.out.println(MyEnum.FIELD1.getFromPojo(p1));
 System.out.println(MyEnum.FIELD2.getFromPojo(p1));
 System.out.println(MyEnum.FIELD3.getFromPojo(p1));

 System.out.println(MyEnum.FIELD1.getFromPojo(p2));
 System.out.println(MyEnum.FIELD2.getFromPojo(p2));
 System.out.println(MyEnum.FIELD3.getFromPojo(p2));

 // in addition, if you've defined 'matchMethod' on POJO
 System.out.println(p1.matchMethod(MyEnum.FIELD1));
 System.out.println(p1.matchMethod(MyEnum.FIELD2));
 System.out.println(p1.matchMethod(MyEnum.FIELD3));

 System.out.println(p2.matchMethod(MyEnum.FIELD1));
 System.out.println(p2.matchMethod(MyEnum.FIELD2));
 System.out.println(p2.matchMethod(MyEnum.FIELD3));
```

This prints:

```
p1
p2
p3
k1
k2
k3
// and optionally...
p1
p2
p3
k1
k2
k3
```

Comment: This doesnt look compatible with  SOLID Prensiple (Open for extension close for modification.) and Couple-Cohesion? so to call POJO class from enum, doesnt look good choice for me.

Comment: It all depends on your use-case, currently MyPojo and MyEnum are already coupled: Remove FIELD3 from the enum, you'll have to change the POJO; add a new field to Pojo, probably you'll also have to change  `MyEnum` . I've tried to facilitate java syntax capabilities, all other solutions will include a level of indirection: Map<Enum, String> and so forth. The choice is yours of course

Answer (score 2):

You can use reflection. Here is an example:

```
public String matchMethod(MyEnum myenum, Map<MyEnum, String> enumToFieldMap) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
    String customFieldName = enumToFieldMap.get(myenum);
    if (customFieldName == null) { // custom field name not found, use default mapping
        return (String) this.getClass().getDeclaredField(myenum.name().toLowerCase()).get(this);
    } // custom field name found in config
    return (String) this.getClass().getDeclaredField(customFieldName).get(this);
}

public String matchMethod(MyEnum myEnum) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
    return matchMethod(myEnum, Collections.EMPTY_MAP);
}
```

There are some drawbacks of using reflection like type safety or traceability, however in this case I think I would choose this option.

**Another**, much more flexible option is to use reflection combined with custom annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface MyEnumRef {
    MyEnum value();
}
```

And common interface:

```
public interface Pojo {
}
```

Declaring new `Pojo`(s) becomes much simpler and cleaner now, and more readable too (at least for some people). It is also very obvious where the actual mapping (configuration) is done.

```
public class MyPojo implements Pojo {
    @MyEnumRef(MyEnum.FIELD1)
    private String field1;
    @MyEnumRef(MyEnum.FIELD2)
    private String field2;
    @MyEnumRef(MyEnum.FIELD3)
    private String field3;
}

public class MyOtherPojo implements Pojo {
    @MyEnumRef(MyEnum.FIELD1)
    private String field1;
    @MyEnumRef(MyEnum.FIELD2)
    private String field2;
}
```

One simple method to rule them all:

```
public String matchMethod(MyEnum myEnum, Pojo myPojo) throws IllegalAccessException {
        for (Field field : myPojo.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
            if (field.isAnnotationPresent(MyEnumRef.class) && field.getAnnotation(MyEnumRef.class).value() == myEnum) {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                return (String) field.get(myPojo);
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
```

It doesn't matter which implementation of `Pojo` you use. There is no overhead when adding new Pojos. Example:

```
private void run() throws IllegalAccessException {
    System.out.println(">>" + matchMethod(MyEnum.FIELD2, new MyPojo("f1", "f2", "f3")));
    System.out.println(">>" + matchMethod(MyEnum.FIELD1, new MyOtherPojo("o1", "o2")));
}
```

Comment: All names might not match with enum.

Answer (score 1):

**This solution only works for `static` fields, since enums are always `static`!**

One way I can imagine is the following:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
   private String field;

   public String getField()
   { return this.field; }


   MyEnum(String field)
   {
      this.field = field;
   }

   FIELD1(field1),
   FIELD2(field2),
   FIELD3(field3),
   ...
}
```

you can even make it generic if you want:

```
public enum MyEnum<T>
{
   private T field;

   public T getField()
   { return this.field; }


   MyEnum(T field)
   {
      this.field = field;
   }

   FIELD1(field1),
   FIELD2(field2),
   FIELD3(field3),
   ...
}
```

Comment: you are completely right. This only works for static fields.... I corrected the answer

Answer (score 1):

Here is yet another way, it does have one level of indirection (registry), but doesn't modify an Enum.

This requires Java 8+, because it uses lambda expressions:

```
import java.util.EnumMap;
import java.util.function.Function;

enum MyEnum {
  FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3;
}

class MyPojo {
  private String field1, field2, field3;

  public MyPojo(String f1, String f2, String f3) {
    this.field1 = f1;
    this.field2 = f2;
    this.field3 = f3;
  }
  private static EnumMap<MyEnum, Function<MyPojo, String>> registry = new EnumMap(MyEnum.class);
  static {
    registry.put(MyEnum.FIELD1, p -> p.field1);
    registry.put(MyEnum.FIELD2, p -> p.field2);
    registry.put(MyEnum.FIELD3, p -> p.field3);
  }

  public String matchMethod(MyEnum e) {
    return registry.get(e).apply(this);
  }
}

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyPojo p1 = new MyPojo("a", "b", "c");
    MyPojo p2 = new MyPojo("x", "y", "z");
    System.out.println(p1.matchMethod(MyEnum.FIELD1));
    System.out.println(p1.matchMethod(MyEnum.FIELD2));
    System.out.println(p1.matchMethod(MyEnum.FIELD3));

    System.out.println(p2.matchMethod(MyEnum.FIELD1));
    System.out.println(p2.matchMethod(MyEnum.FIELD2));
    System.out.println(p2.matchMethod(MyEnum.FIELD3));
  }
}
```

This prints:

```
a
b
c
x
y
z
```